# How to interpret factor predictor variables (+ interaction term) in ordinal logistic regression?

Tags: interaction, interpretation, regression-coefficients, odds-ratio, ordered-logit

Within the ordinal regression formula I included the interaction term "factor(cityname)*suburb" with cityname taking either Edmonton, Halifax, Toronto, or Vancouver and suburb either 0 or 1 (1 if person lives in suburb).
I get [image: this] output, and I am a bit unsure how to interpret this. The last column is the odds ratio / exp(coef), so does this mean that I can interpret it as the following:

- For a person living in Halifax, the odds of being more likely [response variable] is 13.64% lower than for a person living in Edmonton (base case), holding all other variables constant.
- For a person living in a Halifax suburb, the odds of being more likely [response variable] is 65% higher than for a person living in an Edmonton suburb, holding all other variables constant.

I am especially unsure about the interpretation of the interaction term, so it would be great to get some guidance here

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you interpret these terms in an ordinary least squares regression?

Comment: What do you mean? In an ordinary least squares regression I wouldn't have ordinal response variable and odds ratios?

Comment: Say you're trying to predict something using these features, and you elect to use ordinary least squares. How would you interpret the interaction?